# Is there a better way to sum up values of a nested array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I currently have the following items and implementation below. I am not sure if using reduce within another reduce is performant. Is there a better way to sum up nested arrays?

```
const items = [
  {
     id: 111,
     fruits: [
        {
           name: "apple",
           total: 5
        },
        {
           name: "pineapple",
           total: 1
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     id: 222,
     fruits: [
        {
           name: "kiwi",
           total: 2
        }
     ]
  }
];

// my implementation using reduce within another to get the sum of totals.

const sumOfFruits = items
  .reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr.fruits
  .reduce((fruitSum, fruitCurr) => fruitSum + fruitCurr.total));

console.log(sumOfFruits);

// returns 8
```

Comment: Whichever way you go about it, you're going to need two loops (`.reduce()` is implicitly a loop) which will need to visit every `item` element and very `items[x].fruits` element to get your sum., so performance wise you can't get much better (unless you're worried about micro improvements you might get over using a regular `for` loop, which isn't usually worth worry about since the improvement is so small).

Comment: Yes, I also tried with a `for` loop but reduce looked cleaner

Comment: Benchmarks: [Performance of JavaScript .forEach, .map and .reduce vs for and for..of](https://leanylabs.com/blog/js-forEach-map-reduce-vs-for-for_of/) And note that the graphs are ops/sec where the larger numbers are faster.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner (not necessarily faster) way to do this would be:

- collect all "fruits" (`flatMap`)
- pick "totals" (`map`)
- sum the result

```js
const items = [
    {
        id: 111,
        fruits: [
            {
                name: "apple",
                total: 5
            },
            {
                name: "pineapple",
                total: 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 222,
        fruits: [
            {
                name: "kiwi",
                total: 2
            }
        ]
    }
];

//

res = items
    .flatMap(x => x.fruits)
    .map(x => x.total)
    .reduce((s, n) => s + n, 0)

console.log(res)
```

Regarding performance, the thing about javascript is that it's performant enough unless you have millions of objects. And if you do have millions of objects, you shouldn't be using javascript in the first place.

Comment: In  most cases clean readable code is better than verbose performant code, eh?  Up vote for use of flatMap. +1

Comment: Just a pity that it adds a third iteration.

Comment: @trincot: ideally, we need four: `map(prop('fruits')) |> flat |> map(prop('total')) |> sum`

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not produce the desired output: it coerces an object to string and performs string concatenation.

This is because `reduce` is called without second argument, and thus the accumulator gets the first object as value, while you want the accumulated value to be a number.

So you need to add 0 as second argument for the outer `reduce` call. For the inner reduce call you can improve a little bit and provide `sum` as initial value. That way you don't have to do `sum +` anymore.

You can also make use of destructuring in the callback parameters:

This leads to the following code:

```js
const items = [{id: 111,fruits: [{name: "apple",total: 5},{name: "pineapple",total: 1}]},{id: 222,fruits: [{name: "kiwi",total: 2}]}];

const sumOfFruits = items.reduce(
    (sum, {fruits}) => fruits.reduce(
        (fruitSum, {total}) => fruitSum + total,
        sum // Continue with the sum we already have
    ), 0 // Start with 0 for the accumulator
);

console.log(sumOfFruits); // 8
```

Many would agree that this is how it should be done. If performance really is an issue, then you can get a slight improvement by using plain old `for` loops. These do not use callbacks, and so can be expected to do the job a little bit faster, but with less elegant code. In my experience they also perform a tiny bit faster than `for..of` loops:

```js
var items = [{id: 111,fruits: [{name: "apple",total: 5},{name: "pineapple",total: 1}]},{id: 222,fruits: [{name: "kiwi",total: 2}]}];

var sumOfFruits = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var fruits = items[i].fruits;
    for (var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++) {
        sumOfFruits += fruits[j].total;
    }
}
console.log(sumOfFruits); // 8
```

It probably is not worth the millisecond you would gain from this with normal sized input.